# vue-resource http request gives:' _.isArray is not a function

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm trying to get an object from a server at `localhost:3000`. I can see the object when I go to the address in my browser.

My front end runs this function defined in my `Vue` instance's `methods` property:

```
goToTutors: function(){
    this.step='tutors';
    this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/tutors').then(
        function(tutors) {
            console.log("Tutors found!");
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

But in my browser's console, all I see is the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: _.isArray is not a function at vue-resource.js:172

Can anyone point me to the cause of the error?

Comment: It looks like vue-resource is looking for `lodash` (_.isArray is a lodash method) but can't find it. Try to add it to your page.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your vue-resource version. It worked for me.